# mouseover set by jquery not working in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to set the call the function `active()` on onmouseover area on image, i tried to set `onmouseover` using jquery , this work in all browser but not in **IE7** so please anybody suggest me hint to work this code on **IE7**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         var i = 1; 
        $("#map area").each(function(){
            var Id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).attr('onmouseover', "active('area"+i+"','"+Id+"',"+i+")");
            i++
        });
    });
```

the active function code as follow:-

```
function active(value,value2,value3)
    {


        $("#"+value).css({'display':'block'});
        $("#area"+value3+"_link").css({'text-decoration':'underline'});
        $('#'+value2).mouseout(function(){$('#'+value).css({'display':'none'});$("#area"+value3+"_link").css({'color':'#707070','text-decoration':'none'});});
    }
```

and no js error shown.

Comment: What version jQuery are you using? And what does `active()` do?

Comment: Check for any js error and share it with us.

Comment: @putvande  i using the jquery1.9.1 and ative() function displaying the effect of area hover on footer menu item and it shows the hidden container for corresponding area with another background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `$(this).attr('onmouseover'`. Only reason I am seeing is `i`

You can simply use [**.index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$("#map area").on('mouseover',  function(){
    var i = $("#map area").index(this) + 1;
    active('area'+ i, $(this).attr('id'), i);
})
```

Note: `.index()` starts with `0`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to anonymous function definition like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         var i = 1; 
        $("#map area").each(function(){
            var Id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).attr('onmouseover', function() {...your code here...});
            i++;
// and you missed the ; after i++
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:)

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = 1; 
        $("#map area").each(function(){
        var Id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
        active('area"+i+"','"+Id+"',"+i+")");
        i++;
                             });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach event using following func e.g. `addEvent('mouseover', $(this).get(0), <callback>)`

> ```
> function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
> if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
>   elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
> else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
>   elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
> }
> else { // No much to do
>   elem[evnt] = func;
> }
> }
> ```